# My background logo is not right - usage of drawable folders

Tags: android, drawable

I have an ic_action_volume_on in the different hdpi/mdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi. I would have thought that using the following xml content:

```
   <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_volume_on"/>
```

for an xlarge-land would use the right icon automatically from xhdpi but I always get the smallest one. I can always put every icons in drawable an use different icons name but that's annoying.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you have different resolutions in each folder, remember that the base line should be the mdpi and the hdpi is 1.5 * BaseLineReolution 
and xhdpi is 2 * BaseLineReolution, try to refactor it on some image editor if that was the problem, like Photoshop.

Comment: i think xlarge means screen is bigger. it dosen't mean that screen is of xhdpi.

Comment: The way I test is by testing my xlarge-land xml. I really triple check and I'm sure that I have a different sixe for each drawable folder. I'm confused by sush: I thought that having a 32x32 in mdpi, a 64x64 in xhdpi and a 96x96 in xxhdpi was the way to go?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using a `tablet`? Because tablets follow different rules than phones, when it comes to `density slots`.

Comment: sorry I missed the end of your comment. So is there some good explanation on the way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: yes, on the android developer site. Just google for `android supporting multiple screens`